# Autofac - How to access IRegistrationBuilder from IResolvePipelineBuilder & ResolveRequestContext?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, autofac-configuration

I would like to extend my service registration [e.g. `EnableInterfaceInterceptors`] from [Autofac Pipeline](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pipelines.html). However, I couldn't find a way to achieve that. Is there any entrypoint for me to access the registration as `IRegistrationBuilder`?

Provided codes below for your reference

```
containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CredentialService<>)).InstancePerDependency()
.ConfigurePipeline(p =>
{
    p.Use(PipelinePhase.RegistrationPipelineStart, (context, next) =>
    {
        // WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE TO GET BACK THE IRegistrationBuilder IN ORDER TO EXTEND MY REGISTRATION?

        next(context);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Autofac docs

> The context object passed into all middleware is an instance of `ResolveRequestContext`. This object stores the initial attributes of a resolve request, and any properties updated while the request executes.
>
> You can use this context to:
>
> - Check the service being resolved with the `Service` property.
> - Check the `Registration` being used to provide the service.
> - Get or set the result of the resolve operation with the `Instance` property.
> - Access the parameters of the request with the `Parameters` property and change those parameters with the `ChangeParameters` method.
> - Resolve another service (using any of the normal Resolve methods).

### In short

Although it is called registration pipeline, it is actually used when a resolve request occurs.

Instances of `IRegistrationBuilder` are not stored anywhere except in the configuration callback (see details below), hence you cannot access them in the pipeline in any way.

By the time your pipeline delegate is being executed, `IRegistrationBuilder` instances are already gone. You have only the `IComponentRegistration` instance in the `ResolveRequestContext.Registration` property.

### In detail

- When an instance of `IRegistrationBuilder` is created then

  - It will have an instance of `RegistrationData` that contains the `Lifetime`, `Metadata`, `Options`, `Ownership` and `Sharing` properties. *The extension methods of `IRegistrationBuilder` actually configures these properties.*
  - It will also have an instance of `IResolvePipelineBuilder` field you actually configure with the `.ConfigurePipeline()` extension method.
  - It will register a configuration callback into the current `ContainerBuilder` instance with the `IRegistrationBuilder` instance.
- These callbacks are executed by the `ContainerBuilder.Build()` method.
- When the callback is executed then it will create an instance of `IComponentRegistration` from the `IRegistrationBuilder` instance.
- This `IComponentRegistration` contains the same properties that come from the `RegistrationData` and also gets the configured `IResolvePipelineBuilder`.

```cs
var registrationBuilder =
    containerBuilder
        .RegisterType<ServiceWithDependency>()
        .AsSelf()
        .InstancePerDependency();

registrationBuilder.ConfigurePipeline(
    resolvePipelineBuilder =>
    {
        resolvePipelineBuilder.Use(
            PipelinePhase.RegistrationPipelineStart,
            (context, next) =>
            {
                // context is ResolveRequestContext
                // context.Registration is IComponentRegistration

                next(context);

                // Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy
                // EnableInterfaceInterceptors() extension method actually uses
                // - context.Registration
                // - context.Instance (this will be overridden with the generated proxy)
                // - context.ResolveService(...)

                // You may also use these properties from context.Registration
                // - context.Registration.Lifetime
                // - context.Registration.Metadata
                // - context.Registration.Options
                // - context.Registration.Ownership
                // - context.Registration.Sharing
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks @Gabor, very detail explanation. So, does it mean that I could learn deal with `EnableInterfaceInterceptors()` from `ConfigurePipeline()` by registrating a component with `EnableInterfaceInterceptors()` once in normal way and then see what have been added into `context.Registration`, `context.Instance` and `context.ResolveService`?

Comment: update: I have searched through the `context.Registration` before `next(context)` but did not find any related information related to DynamicProxy/Interceptor even I tried to register the service with `EnableInterfaceInterceptors()`. I expect there should be some flag/identifier from `context.Registration` to specify this service will be intercepted

Comment: @mannok, when you call `EnableInterfaceInterceptors()` method on your registration, it will configure only a callback delegate for the pipeline but that delegate will only be executed when you or the app tries to resolve something. This delegate uses those properties I mentioned. So you can't check what have been added right after your method call because at that time it has not been executed yet. You can check what that method exactly does [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/RegistrationExtensions.cs#L155).